# Read an Nginx log file and get the IPs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nginx

I am making a program and I need to read an Nginx log file containing IPs. The file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2020:19:19:55 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2020:19:19:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2020:19:19:45 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"
```

As I said, I only need the first part, which is the IP, and save it into a new .txt file. At the moment I have the following code to read it, but I am not be able get only the IP:

```
with open('/var/log/nginx/access.log', 'r') as f:
    ip_list = f.readlines()
```

This code returns this list:

```
['127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2020:19:19:55 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"\n', '\n', 
'127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2020:19:19:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"\n', '\n', 
'127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2020:19:19:45 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"\n', '\n']
```

Now I only need get the IPs and create a new file with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string line by `--` and capture the first element to get the IP(s) and finally write to a new log file only those IP(s) on each line.

```
with open('/var/log/nginx/access.log', 'r') as f:
    log_line = f.readlines()

ip_list = [ line.split('- -')[0].strip() for line in log_line]
print(ip_list)
with open('/var/log/nginx/access_ips.log', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(ip_list))
```

**N.B** you can use regex pattern match to get only the IP(s) or any other ways also as it can be done by many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Is python required? you could do it this way :

```
cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print $1}' > nginx_log_ips.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of regex in order to find all the IPv4 IPs out of the log files.

```
import re

# Loading the contents of the log file
f = open('/var/log/nginx/access.log', 'r')
text_to_search = f.read()
f.close()


# Regex for IPv4
ip_pattern = re.compile("\d\d?\d?\.\d\d?\d?\.\d\d?\d?\.\d\d?\d?")

# Finding all the IPs
results = ip_pattern.findall(text_to_search)

# Loop to print all the IPv4 addresses
for result in results:
    print(result)
```